# Error inflating class DynamicGridView on Tablet

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using a DynamicGridView in my Android app. Everything works perfectly on my phone, but when I tried to run the app on a tablet, it crashed after I Login to it,after login it will go to Main Activity where it will using DynamicGridView layout.

The Error is saying that :

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.*.*/com.*.*.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error
>   inflating class com.*.*.dynamicgrid.DynamicGridView

...

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.hvms20, PID: 7477
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hvms20/com.example.hvms20.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.example.hvms20.dynamicgrid.DynamicGridView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.example.hvms20.dynamicgrid.DynamicGridView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.example.hvms20.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
    at com.example.hvms20.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "@2131361797"
    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(XmlUtils.java:122)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getInt(TypedArray.java:255)
    at android.widget.GridView.<init>(GridView.java:137)
    at android.widget.GridView.<init>(GridView.java:110)
    at com.example.hvms20.dynamicgrid.DynamicGridView.<init>(DynamicGridView.java:106)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:696) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:839) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:745) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
    at com.example.hvms20.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:54) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Application terminated.

Above show the Error that I trying solve for ages.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    photo_iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.item_img);

    titleText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.item_title);
```

Above is my line #54 in my MainActivity it refer to "setContentView(R.layout...)"

```
public DynamicGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super (context, attrs);
    init(context);
}
```

Above is line #106 on my DynamicGridView it refer to "super (context, attrs)"

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main">
</include>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
```

Above is my .XML the them i used is android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<com.example.hvms20.dynamicgrid.DynamicGridView
    android:id="@+id/dynamic_grid"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:numColumns="@integer/column_count"
    />
```

This is my content_main.xml

What I don't understand is that how come a DynamicGridView is workable on a phone and not workable in a tablet.

Thanks in advance for helping me if need more information I can provide it.

Comment: paste xml layout too and theme component and type of activity (activity/appcompat)

Comment: Where is gridview in your xml ? Please paste this code.

Comment: Is this okay ? really need help since am really new in this Java android development.

Comment: I think you are missing some constructor in `DynamicGridView`

Comment: I used multiple layout in my main activity can someone guide how to show you guys my code soo that you guys can see the problem clearly, if I paste it all it here it will be a very long question.